# Rollback multiple update queries if one fails

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple `UPDATE` queries that change the group name in the `tbl_groups` table at first, and then update all the users in the `tbl_users` table that belong to those groups. However, when the user update query fails, those group names have already been updated. What I want is update both together or neither, and I am using PHP and MySQL.

Comment: This might be a little bizarre and 100% incorrect (so please let me know if it's out of the question), but maybe you can create a temporary mysql table and insert the results (on success) into the main table. Thoughts?

Comment: I would suggest, checking if a user update query failed and if so revert the changes to the group table. I do not think it is possible to prepare the complete statement, running it without actually running it and checking it for errors. The one problem is, if with 'user update' fails you mean a fatal MySQL error, that than of course the rest of the script will not be executed.

Comment: You need use InnoDB engine and transaction.

Comment: this updates in a second but I am thinking when I put it on an external server, and if something goes wrong, am using php statement like `if(mysqli_query(query1) && mysqli_query(query2)) {echo 'success';}` but here though `query2` failes, `query1` gets executed

Comment: In what way could either update query fail?

Comment: put everything in a single transaction. that's exactly what they are for.

Comment: @Supericy if at that very point the connection is out, i know it's too rare but.

Comment: @AcidicCloud In that case, as others have said, transactions are what you're looking for.

Comment: @Supericy so I need to study that now, thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like all you need to do is use transactions.

You must use InnoDB tables to use transactions (actually, some other DB engines have transactions, but InnoDB is most common with MySQL).

Issue the "BEGIN TRANSACTION" query before the first update.

If any query fails, issue the "ROLLBACK" query to undo everything.

It's really pretty simple.

And if you ever decide you want to do a partial rollback (back to some point after the beginning of the transaction), then you can use "ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT savepoint_name". You will have had to issue the "SAVEPOINT savepoint_name" query 1st.

E.g., in PHP

```
mysql_query("BEGIN TRANSACTION");

$result1 = mysql_query("UPDATE `tbl_groups` SET `user_id` = 5 WHERE `group_id` = 3");
if($result1 === false) {
mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
}

mysql_query("SAVEPOINT savepoint1");

$result2 = mysql_query("UPDATE `tbl_users` SET `group_id` = 3 WHERE `user_id` = 5");

if($result === false) {
ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT savepoint1;
}
// COMMIT saves the changes to the db, making them visible to other sessions
// if the ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT statement executed, then only changes up to that SAVEPOINT will be saved
// if no ROLLBACK statements were executed, then all changes will be saved (assuming no MySQL errors that cause implicit ROLLBACK)
mysql_query('COMMIT');
```

Comment: To commit a transaction at some point `mysql_query("COMMIT");`

Comment: In your code, the changes will not commit to the DB

Comment: @AdilMalik I added that statement and an explanation about how it works with the `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

use transactions with the best isolation level

i prefer **"repeatable read"**( you cannot view others data and vise verse until you committed the transaction ) is always good and it is default for innodb storage engine

if you are not using innodb then change the isolation level with

SET GLOBAL tx_isolation='REPEATABLE-READ'; or

SET SESSION tx_isolation='REPEATABLE-READ';

the rest of details are given by @Buttle Butkus

Answer (score 0):

Set the relation between tbl_groups and tbl_users to `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Then just update tbl_groups and the changes will cascade to related records in tbl_users. If you have to update your parent keys like this very often then you could maybe think about using a surrogate key instead.

Answer (score 0):

Following example is based on object oriented style, make sure your Required database table Type is InnoDB as it supports transaction statement

Here i just want delete multiple record based on ids

```
$this->link_id->autocommit(FALSE);
```

// This above statement start the transaction by disabling auto commit where link_id refers to your MySQLi database connection

```
        for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){     

            $tSql = "DELETE FROM your_table" 
                     . " WHERE id=" . $i;

            $rs = $this->link_id->query($tSql);// execute the query

            if($this->link_id->affected_rows == -1) // check if it fails
            {   
               $_SESSION["error"] = "Sorry ! cant be deleted ! ";           
                $this->link_id->rollback(); // rollback the transaction
                break; // break the loop

            }           

        }



//check if there is some error or not, if no error then commit the transaction
        if(empty($_SESSION["error"])){          
            $this->link_id->commit();
        }
```